# SQL use reverse function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, reverse

So i have data that full with name, i need to get the last name

example
name : first middle last or first last
so i need to get the last name using charindex and reverse function but i dont want the last name reversed became tasl.

sorry for my bad english

i tried using charindex to find where is the space for the last name
Charindex(' ', REVERSE(Name))
but i got no idea because i need to use substring to add more text after i got the last name

Comment: CHARINDEX is not a known function for `mysql`, so I dropped the tag.

Comment: what about parsename()?   parsename(replace(name,' ','.'),1)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us examples of the names you need to handle, including the edge cases.

Comment: There are regions where the "first name" is the family name. Sometimes family names are are the "last name" but may be two words right after the first name being the given one having three words

Comment: Consider edge cases including trailing spaces, Sammy Davis Jr., J.R. Ewing III, Madonna, Prince (a.k.a. Ƭ̵̬̊), Doogie Howser M.D., Ichiro Suzuki (which one is his last name?), etc. Cleaning up names and extracting name parts is unimaginably complex, and it is much better to store the parts separately in the first place.

Comment: China's premier Xi Jinping's first name is Jinping not Xi for example

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT
   name,
   parsename(replace(name,' ','.'),1) usingParseName,
   substring(name,len(name) - Charindex(' ', REVERSE(Name))+2,200) usingCharIndex
FROM person
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/lvnB8WVJ)

Comment: Great, but should trim or translate to avoid [problems with trailing spaces](https://dbfiddle.uk/I_FOwW1F).

Comment: Who want to add space(s) to a name, when storing this in a VARCHAR field?  Cleaning up spaces is an application job, and not a database job.

Comment: Nobody _wants_ to add space(s) to a name, but it's pretty common. I upvoted your answer I just want to mention that it could be a little safer by ignoring spaces, that's all. You don't have to do anything with that information, but the OP might want to.